# UITableView leaves pattern of blank cells after deleting one or more rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

[TableView leaving blank cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k5Kd.gif)

[Repeating blank cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qch37.gif)

[When deleting rows from the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gpZo.gif)

After deleting a row or multiple rows in my TableView, the TableView Cells seems to shift or refresh in an odd way that creates multiple blank rows. Seems to start with rows that are off-screen.

I have tried using beginUpdates, endUpdates, and performBatchUpdates with no change in behavior. I have also confirmed that the data source array is being updated properly and so is the number of rows in the tableview.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return paymentsArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! UserPaymentCell

    let payment = paymentsArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.payment = payment

    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 75, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    let payment = paymentsArray[indexPath.row]

    if payment.payerUID == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let payment = paymentsArray[indexPath.row]

    switch editingStyle {
    case .delete:
        deleteBillAndRefreshTotals(bill: payment, indexPath: indexPath)
    default:
        return
    }
}

func deleteBillAndRefreshTotals(bill: Bill, indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("DELETING CELL")
    paymentsArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    paymentsTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    print(paymentsTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0))
}
```

Expected results - for row to be deleted and all cells above or below the deleted cell to shift together.

Comment: May we see the data source methods please?

Comment: @matt Included the data source methods for you!

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything wrong with it, except that the `deleteRows` should be wrapped in a `performBatchUpdates`. If that doesn't solve it, can you post a small test project that demonstrates the issue? Basically it should consist of little more than the code you've already posted.

Comment: By the way here's my downloadable example project and you can see that it doesn't display this problem. https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch08p445deleteTableRows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse() // <--
    self.nameLabel.text = nil
    self.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

Within my custom cell implementation, the above function was being called *without* calling `super.prepareForReuse` first. Therefore causing the issues above.

Answer (score 0):

```
after perform delete operations call reloaddata method so after that tableview will refresh.
 func deleteBillAndRefreshTotals(bill: Bill, indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("DELETING CELL")
    paymentsArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    paymentsTableView.reloaddata()
    print(paymentsTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
paymentsTableView.beginUpdates()
paymentsTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
paymentsTableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried this and it still shows the same behavior, as well as performBatchUpdates.

Comment: @chenders I'm waiting for you to supply a reproducible example project.

Comment: @matt Not sure about the best way to post a small sample of it. Do you just need the link to the full project on GitHub?

Comment: @chenders The point is for you to reproduce the issue in a small plain vanilla project and post _that_ on github. You see, I'm assuming that you won't be able to — because the problem is due to totally different code elsewhere in your real project that you have not shown us. I am _challenging_ you to show me this problem in a _minimal_ project, not your full project. I showed _you_ a demo project where this problem does _not_ happen. Now you show me a demo project where it does.

Comment: @matt I did what you suggested, and it did not reproduce the issue. So I looked at the possibility that it had something to do with the custom cell itself. Sure enough, I looked at the prepareForReuse func I had... commented it out and it worked like it should. Quickly realized I was not calling super.prepareForReuse within the function first, causing some of my cells to change to blank white cells. Thanks for suggesting to strip it all back!

Comment: @chenders Yep, that's my go-to debugging technique!